# AWS Step Function: ignore input from previous state, and use "Parameters" as input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

So I have a state defined as below.

```
    "process-abc": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:my-lambda...",
      "Parameters": {
        "type": "my-type",
      },
```

However, when I run step function, I don't see the `"type": "my-type",` in the state input, I only see the input as something from the previous state output.

How can I only pass `"type": "my-type"` as the only input into the current state?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not define any result path, by default input to the next state is the output of the previous state.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html

You can set the result path of the state 1 to `null` to ignore the state 1 result and pass the state 1 input to the state 2.